# How can i use sed to exclude patterns when joining lines together?

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to look for lines that start with '1' and join them with the following line, while ignoring lines that start with '1.'
my source file looks like this:

```
name  cat 
1 
7.75 
2 
1.27 
X 
5.10
```

The desired output is:

```
name  cat 
1 7.75 
2 
1.27 
X 
5.10
```

I have a command that looks for lines that start with 1 and joins the following line, however because I also have lines with 1.* which i want to ignore. I have tried the following sed command and used  to try and ignore decimals, however it does not work.
The command i am using is:

```
sed '/^\<1\>/N;s/\n/ /'
```

but it gives this output:

```
name  cat 
1  7.75 
2 
1.27  X 
5.10
```

How can I join lines starting with '1' with the following line, while ignoring lines that start with 1.* ?

Edit:

- I only want to join lines that contain '1' (nothing else on the line) with the following line
- Some lines start with a float , eg 1.2 , i want to ignore these so the next line is not appended to this.

Comment: 1) does "ignore lines that start with `1.`" mean they should or should not be appended to a preceding line that starts with `1`? 2) Is `123` a line that "starts with `1`" or not? 3) Should multiple consecutive lines that start with `1` be appended to each other or not? Please [edit] your question to clarify and improve the example to cover all the use cases.

Comment: lines that start with 1. should be appended if the previous line starts with 1,  multiple lines that start with 1 are not in my data, all is the same format, only different values is the decimals,

Comment: Could you please provide sample for this `However, if the line before the decimal is '1' then the decimal should be appended to it even if its a float beginning with 1.` in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Also what should be done if there are 2 continuous `1`s are coming in back to back lines?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have removed this comment because it over complicates it and is not relevant

Comment: You don't have any lines containing only `1` in your example input - you do have `1 `, but that's not the same.

Comment: `'1' (nothing else on the line)` - your input has a space after the 1. `these should both be treated as '1'` So there __can__ be something else on the line, it looks contradictory. Please be specific. What else can be on the line? What cannot? Lines containing `1 ` are not exactly lines containing `1`.

Comment: these should both be treated as '1' because their is no following decimal point

Comment: You also don't have any lines starting with `12`, for example, so some of us are assuming you only want to join to lines that start with the number `1` while others are assuming you want to join to lines that start with a number that starts with `1`. Again, please include that case in your example so we can clearly see how multi-digit numbers that start with `1` should be handled.

Comment: this is correct, only lines that are exactly '1', '12' should be ignored

Comment: But lines that contain `1<white space>` as in the first line of your example should not be ignored, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/^1/{/^1\./!N;s/\n/ /}'
```

If a line does start with a `1`, then if it does not start with `1.` then append next line. Then replace the newline for a space.

Or just:

```
sed '/^1\([^\.]\|$\)/N;s/\n/ /'
# same without `\(\|\)`
sed '/^1[^\.]/N;/^1$/N;s/\n/ /'
```

If a line start with a `1` and then has anything else then a comma or it's the end of line, then append next line. Replace the newline for a space

> I only want to join lines that contain '1' (nothing else on the line) with the following line

So just match the `1`.

```
sed '/^1$/N;s/\n/ /'
```

Maybe you want to just match `1` followed by any whitespace?

```
sed '/^1[[:space:]]*$/N;s/\n/ /'
```

Or by spaces only?

```
sed '/^1 *$/N;s/\n/ /'
```

The [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a great place to learn how to use sed. To learn regexes, I recommend playing with [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/), they let you learn regexes fast and with fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can begin your sed script by starting a new cycle when a line begins with `1.`:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^1\./n   # don't change 1.x
/^1\b/N   # \b is GNU sed word-boundary
s/\n/ /
```

Thus, only lines not beginning `1.` get the following line appended.

Example output:

```
name  cat 
1  7.75 
2 
1.27 
X 
5.10
```

---

According to later comments on the question, it seems you only want to join lines containing `1` and optional trailing spaces, which makes the script much simpler:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^1[[:space:]]*$/N   # match the whole line
y/\n/ /
```

Comment: What is `\>` doing in `/^1\>/N` and why is it ignored?

Comment: i used \> in my original command in an attempt to ignore lines that have other characters after '1' however this did not work

Comment: @Kamil, I took that from the question, assuming it's a syntax extension in OP's sed.  I'm guessing it's meant to be `\b`, so I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Just a side note: `is standard sed word-boundary` - `\s` `\b` are GNU extensions, not "standard" as per [posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). They don't work with bsd sed and macos sed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
$0==1{
  prev=$0
  next
}
prev{
  $0=prev OFS $0
  prev=""
}
1
END{
  if(prev){
    print prev
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
$0==1{               ##Checking condition if line is having 1 value then do following.
  prev=$0            ##Creating variable prev and set its value to current line value.
  next               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
prev{                ##Checking condition if prev variable is NOT NULL then do following.
  $0=prev OFS $0     ##Setting current line value to prev OFS and current line.
  prev=""            ##Nullifing variable prev here.
}
1                    ##1 will print the edited/non-edited line here.
END{                 ##Starting END block for this awk program here.
  if(prev){          ##Checking condition if variable prev is NOT NULL then do following.
    print prev       ##Printing variable prev here.
  }                  ##Closing BLOCK for if condition here.
}                    ##Closing END block of this awk program here.
' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1  7.75
2
1.27
X
5.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, ($1==1"" ? OFS : ORS)}' file
name  cat
1  7.75
2
1.27
X
5.10
```

FYI some (all?) of the sed solutions posted so far are relying on non-[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) functionality and so YMMV depending on what they do depending on which sed you use.